# Querying already exsiting database returns empty cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite

[image]

I'm not very familiar with sql but what I'm am simply trying to do is get two values from an already created database file."Balance" and "VoucherBalance". While I attempt to query the database I get either get back an empty cursor when I add the third and forth params to the query method, or if I leave third and forth params as null I get back a count of 1 which is just the names of the two columns I'm trying to acquire.

Why am I not getting the values when I am specifying which ones I want?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DataBaseReader extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String TAG = "DataBaseReader";
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/PACKAGENAME/databases/DATABAENAME.db";
    private static String DB_NAME = "TABLENAME";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public double balance;
    public int voucher;
    private final Context myContext;
    public String text = "";


    public DataBaseReader(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void getWireAccountBalance()
    {
        String[] projection = {DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_BALANCE, DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_VOUCHER};
        String[] selectionArgs = {"Balance", "VoucherBalance"};
        String selection = DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_BALANCE + "=?" + " AND " + DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_VOUCHER + "=?";
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseContract.Database.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);


        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor count is " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        text = Arrays.toString(cursor.getColumnNames());
        Toast.makeText(myContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            while (!cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                balance = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_BALANCE));
                voucher = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_VOUCHER));
            }
        } else
        {

            Log.d(TAG, "Cursor count is " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        super.close();
        if (database != null)
        {
            close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `moveTofirst` moves to the first row, you then use `moveToNext`, which will return false (when there is just the one row), skipping the first row.

I'd suggest using :-

```
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        balance = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_BALANCE));
        voucher = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_VOUCHER));
    }
```

instead of :-

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        while (!cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            balance = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_BALANCE));
            voucher = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Database.COLUMN_VOUCHER));
        }
    } else
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor count is " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
    }
```